# Angular 8: How can I show multiple data in table header in a column & can sort data on clicking specific header attribute?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-table

I am using angular material 8. I need to show multiple header values in a column and its respective values in body as well as I want to sort the data table according to the specific header value when i click that header value. 
How can I do it?

Here is the data table I want:

[image]

I want to show the multiple values in data table as shown in the picture as well as when I click on `no.` attribute in the first column, the data table should get sorted according to the `no`, when I click `name` in the first column, the data table should get sorted according to the `name`.

I dont want same data to be displayed just wanted to show multiple attribute and sort them in a column.

Here is another image.
[image]

Comment: While you could roll your own to get a table that will act like this, I would suggest having the table such that the individual headers on the columns do the sorting, like is standard in most all cases. With the image you have here, you are displaying the same data multiple times, which will likely confuse your users. I would suggest looking into some third party components that will give you a table with all the sorting and searching built in (there are many sources out there that are free).

Comment: edited the question..i dont want data to be displayed multiple times but wanted to have multiple data in a column with sorting specifically